# Gradle submodule available only for component scan

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

I have a gradle multi-module project to integrate with different systems.

So I have a main module(say `Integration`) And serveral submodules for each system(`Sub1`, `Sub2`, etc)

The plan is,

- To have different modules for each system that we integrate with and have the implementations from those modules used dynamically using factory or some other loosely coupled patterns.
- The modules `Sub1`, `Sub2`, etc will use classes from `Integration` directly but not the other way around.
- I have my `settings.gradle` this way,

```
rootProject.name = 'IntegrationProject'

include 'Integration'
include(":Sub1")
project(":Sub1").projectDir = file("Sub1")
```

- And in the `Sub*` projects I have dependency definition to use the implementation from `Integration` module directly. And it works.

But when I run the application class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, it's not scanning the classes in `Sub1` module. How to achieve this?